# Find Corner in image with low resolution (Checkerboard)

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

i need some help with a corner detection. 
I printed a checkerboard and created an image of this checkerboard with a webcam. The problem is that the webcam has a low resolution, therefore it do not find all corners. So i enhanced the number of searched corner. Now it finds all corner but different one for the same Corner. 
All Points are stored in a matrix therefore i don't know which element depends to which point. 
(I can not use the checkerboard function because the fuction is not available in my Matlab Version)
I am currently using the matlab function corner. 
My Question:
Is it possible to search the Extrema of all the point clouds to get 1 Point for each Corner? Or has sb an idea what i could do ? --> Please see the attached photo
Thanks for your help!
[image]

Comment: I remember few years ago when I was working on this stuff I needed very accurate images. Not only I needed to get into the camera and get the raw data, uncompressed, to get good corners (your photo is clearly a jpg or some other compressed type) but I also needed to go to an specialized printing shop so the ink on the paper was of good quality. Conclusion: use crappy hardware, get crappy results (and vice-versa). You can process this image as much as you want, if the raw data is not good, it will never be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the image my guess is that the false positives of the corner detection are caused by [compression artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact) introduced by the lossy compression algorithm used by your webcam's image acquisition software. You can clearly spot [ringing artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts#JPEG) around the edges of the checkerboard fields.

You could try two different things:

1. Check in your webcam's acquisition software whether you can disable the compression or change to a lossless compression
2. Working with the image you already have, you could try to alleviate the impact of the compression by binarising the image using a simple thresholding operation (which in the case of a checkerboard would not even mean loosing information since the image is intrinsically binary).

In case you want to go for option 2) I would suggest to do the following steps. Let's assume the variable storing your image is called `img`

- look at the distribution of grey values using e.g. the [imhist](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html) function like so: `imhist(img)`
- Ideally you would see a clean bimodal distribution with no overlap. Choose an intensity value `I` in the middle of the two peaks
- Then simply binarize by assigning `img(img<I) = 0; img(img>I) = 255` (assuming img is of type uint8).
- Then run the corner algorithm again and see if the outliers have disappeared